# MySQL query returns different results on windows and unix

Tags: mysql

i have two tables, temp_students and exam_verify.
temp_students contains surname, othername and exam_number of students,
and exam_verify contains a column which is a concatenation of surname,othername and exam_number (with all empty strings replaced) of previous candidates who have taken the exam.
 i am trying to fetch those prospective students whose surname, othernames and exam numbers are an exact in exam_verify.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT d.surname,d.othernames,d.exam_number FROM temp_students d 
WHERE UPPER(REPLACE(CONCAT(d.surname,d.othernames,d.exam_number),' ','')) NOT IN 
(SELECT s.exact_search_code FROM exam_verify s);
```

But when i run this on mysql (same versions) on a windows machine it works, but when i run it on same dataset on mysql on solaris i get the opposite result.

what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using differet client on the same server or even the server is on different platform? Could you verify you didn't have any TYPO?

Comment: Hi Alepac, i have verified and there is no typo. not sure what you mean by different client. I am using mysql workbench to run my queries.

Comment: mysql on win/solaris, hope you mean server. Can you post db creation & table creation sqls?

Comment: hi tuxuday, yea i mean mysql server insalled on my dev win7 pc, give different result with specified query from the mysql(same verson) on solaris with same dataset.

Comment: i found the problem. the exam_number column from the temp_students had a new line character at the end. It was loaded from a csv file. How can i work around this, thank you.